Source for Avraham Avinu torturing himself
I remember seeing in a sefer that Avraham physically tortured himself in order to learn about his weaknesses. I can't seem to recall which sefer that was in. Can anyone help me out?

I seem to recall the wording to be something along the lines of "מנאץ ומגדף את עצמו" if that helps at all.
